# Use the definition of the limit of a sequence to show that $\lim_{x \to \infty } \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

Use the definition of the limit of a sequence to show that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1}=0$$

I'm really not sure where to start. I'm new to analysis, so maybe just guiding me in the right direction with some hints would be great. I thought about doing the value of $$|a_{n}-a|<\epsilon$$
So, $$\left\lvert\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1}\right\rvert < \epsilon$$
$$\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}<\epsilon$$
Then, I'm not sure what to do. Should I use the algebraic limit theorem: $\lim(a_{n}/b_{n}) = a/b$    if $b \neq 0$? So, I find a value of $a_{n} < \epsilon$ and $b_{n} < \epsilon$ and then prove by saying: *For any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a positive integer $N$ such that if $n > N$ then $|a_{n}-a|<\epsilon$* and do the same thing for $|b_{n}-b| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Do you know the Archimedean property?

Comment: I assume you meant to write $\lim_{\color{red}{n} \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n + 1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're being asked to use the definition of the limit.  So, let's start there.

You need to show that no matter what $\epsilon>0$ you're given, you can make the difference between $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1}$ and $0$ small (less than $\epsilon$) by making $n$ sufficiently large.

What happens when you make $n$ large?  Notably, the numerator is $\sqrt{n}$, and the denominator is pretty close to $n$.  So, the whole thing should act kind of like $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.  That should be our target for proving this.

To that end: note that
$$
\left\lvert\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1}-0\right\rvert=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1}<\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.
$$

So, let $\epsilon>0$ be given, and choose $N$ so that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}<\epsilon$. Then for any $n>N$, you have
$$
\left\lvert\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+1}-0\right\rvert<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}<\epsilon.
$$
This proves that this sequence converges to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $\varepsilon>0$. If $n\in\Bbb N$, since$$\frac{\sqrt n}{n+1}<\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n+1}=\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}},$$in order to prove that $\frac{\sqrt n}{n+1}<\varepsilon$, it's enough to prove that $\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}<\varepsilon$, which is equivalent to $n+1>\frac1{\varepsilon^2}$. So, take $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $N>\frac1{\varepsilon^2}-1$, and then$$n\geqslant N\implies\frac{\sqrt n}{n+1}<\varepsilon.$$